# Convert a 2D array to 3D array by multiplying vector in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an 2D numpy array `a=[[1,-2,1,0], [1,0,0,-1]]`, but I want to convert it to an 3D numpy array by element-wise multiply a vector `t=[[x0,x0,x0,x0],[x1,x1,x1,x1]]` where `xi` is a 1D numpy array with 3072 size. So the result would be `a*t=[[x0,-2x0,x0,0],[x1,0,0,-x1]]` with the size (2,4,3072). So how should I do that in Python numpy?

Comment: ```np.outer(np.array([[1, -2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, -1]]), np.random.random(size=3072))``` returns a shape of ```(8, 3072)```, so can it be that you are looking for this kind of operation?

Comment: Does this have to be done with numpy? It's much easier with the standard library, actually

Comment: @sascha, No, I'm looking forward to expending the array dimension.

Comment: @bendl, actually it has to be done with numpy without any for loop, or it would be meaningless.

Comment: Extending is easy, especially 8 to 2x4 (reshape). The more relevant question here is: are you trying to implement some common math-op without declaring it as such (and maybe different input to outer would work).

Comment: @sascha, yes, I'm trying to implement generic function which would convert any 2d array to 3d array by multiplying an array of vector. You can think of making each number in the 2-d array to be an vector by multiplying some vector xi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
import numpy as np

# Example data taken from bendl's answer !!!
a = np.array([[1,-2,1,0], [1,0,0,-1]])
xi = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = np.outer(a, xi).reshape(a.shape[0], -1, len(xi))

print('a:')
print(a)
print('b:')
print(b)
```

Output:

```
a:
[[ 1 -2  1  0]
 [ 1  0  0 -1]]
b:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [-2 -4 -6]
  [ 1  2  3]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 1  2  3]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [-1 -2 -3]]]
```

As i said: it looks like an [outer-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) and splitting/reshaping this one dimension is easy.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Isn't `xi` supposed to be 2D, like `xi = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`?

Comment: Not according to his words (*where xi is a 1D numpy array with 3072 size*; at least that's my interpretation).

Comment: @DavidHx I edited the reshape-operation (more generic now). You will need it with different number of rows!

Comment: No, but `t` is supposed to be 2D: `(2, 3072)`. And the product we are looking for is between `a` and `t`, not between `a` and `xi` (which is only one row of `t`).

Comment: I just followed his positive remark about bendl's solution. The math might be off, sure...

Comment: Yup, if you look closely at `b` you can see you're multiplying `x0` for both rows of `a`, whereas you should be multiplying `x0` for the first and `x1` for the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting for this:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, -2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, -1]])
t = numpy.arange(3072 * 2).reshape(2, 3072)
# array([[   0,    1,    2, ..., 3069, 3070, 3071],            # = x0
#        [3072, 3073, 3074, ..., 6141, 6142, 6143]])           # = x1
a.shape
# (2, 4)
t.shape
# (2, 3072)

c = (a.T[None, :, :] * t.T[:, None, :]).T
# array([[[    0,     1,     2, ...,  3069,  3070,  3071],     # =  1 * x0
#         [    0,    -2,    -4, ..., -6138, -6140, -6142],     # = -2 * x0
#         [    0,     1,     2, ...,  3069,  3070,  3071],     # =  1 * x0
#         [    0,     0,     0, ...,     0,     0,     0]],    # =  0 * x0
# 
#        [[ 3072,  3073,  3074, ...,  6141,  6142,  6143],     # =  1 * x1
#         [    0,     0,     0, ...,     0,     0,     0],     # =  0 * x1
#         [    0,     0,     0, ...,     0,     0,     0],     # =  0 * x1
#         [-3072, -3073, -3074, ..., -6141, -6142, -6143]]])   # = -1 * x1

c.shape
# (2, 4, 3072)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,-2,1,0], [1,0,0,-1]])
xi = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a = np.dstack([a * i for i in xi])
```

The docs for this are here: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html

Comment: The result is what I need, but can you do it without any for-loop? Because it may affect performance.